# Wordpress image name case sensitive giving 404 error

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a site in WordPress. In that site name of images giving a 404 error. Like, if I have an image with URL www.example.com/my-image.jpg. So, when I enter URL www.example.com/My-image.jpg, its gives me a 404 error. Notice M is capital. Please suggest me some solution with .htaccess or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice won't be to solve it with a script but to rename all images to be lower-case.
I would suggest to use a renaming tool on your local machine and then re-upload all using FTP.
In your code you should refactor.

It may sound like some work to do, but this is how things should work correctly

Comment: If someone enter a image name as capital, its gives 404 error.